# Design pattern for multiple output formats

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, encapsulation, file-format

I have a class structure which represents (internally) the data I wish to output to a file.

Some of the member variables are private to the data class  so that it can manage itself and stop things going awry.

I then want this data to be output into a number of file formats. I could do something like

```
savefile_formatA(DataClass* pDataClass, ofstream& fout);
savefile_formatB(DataClass* pDataClass, ofstream& fout);
```

except that the functions need to then see the private member variables of `DataClass`. I could of course just make `savefile_formatXYZ()` friend functions but then I would need to add a friend declaration for every different format.

Is there a standard design pattern for solving this kind of thing? How would you solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what formats do you mean ? are you thinking of generic formats like .txt .xls .doc or so or a private format that is specific to each class ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending upon the complexity of your data class you may wish to use a Visitor pattern. If you have some kind of nested data structure then Visitor may well be what you need.

If formatting is something relatively simple, for example you are producing variations on something  such as a comma separated list then you can take an approach like this.

Your formatter objects all implement an interface such as (pseudo code)

```
 IFormatter ( start(); addInt(name, value), addString(name, value) .... end() );
```

then the data class has a method

```
  public void formatMyself( IFormatter formatter ) {

        formatter.start()
        formatter.addString("aField", myA);
        formatter.addInteger("bfield", myB);
        formatter.end();          
  }
```

This makes the class being formatted responsible for the choice of data to be formatted, and the formatter responsible for the details of the format.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to implement file formatting and save/load from *outside* of the class, then you can only do it with data that is publicly available. If saving/loading needs to deal with non-public data, if reloading the class cannot reconstruct the original non-public data from public data, then either the class itself or friends of that class must be involved. There's not really a way around that.

The most you might be able to do is to make it easier to write new types, with a friend template. For example:

```
class DataType
{
...
private:
    template<typename format> friend void SaveFile<format>(const DataType *, ofstream&);
};
```

The `format` template type would be empty types. So if you have formatA and formatB, you would have empty structs:

```
struct FormatA {};
struct FormatB {};
```

Then, all you need to do is write specialized versions of SaveFile for those formats:

```
template<> void SaveFile<FormatA>(const DataType *, ofstream&);
template<> void SaveFile<FormatB>(const DataType *, ofstream&);
```

They will automatically be friends of DataType.

Comment: Combined with the visitor above this is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution would be to decide what data needs to be exported,
and to provide some sort of access (probably getter functions) to it.
Logically, you don't want the class itself to have to know any details
about the formats, and you don't want the formatters to know anything
more about the class than the data it has to format.

Comment: Indeed, I thought about this but the data could be large so any getters would need to pass by reference / pointer. But does this not break encapsulation too?

Comment: @Dan, No. Public interfaces are well controlled by your class while friend isn't. Consider you add more private data in your data class future, which you don't want expose to formatters though. If you use friend class, you have no way to prevent it.

Comment: Original deleted: I was responding to a different question.  If you're outputting the data to an external support, it isn't really private anyway.  The getters will be returning const references or values, so they won't allow modification (unlike `friend`).  And since the getters are for formatting, performance won't be an issue anyway; you might want to define an artificial struct with all of the data, and just have a single getter returning it by value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have here is one of design.  Serializing to a file shouldn't be *modifying* that data in anyway, so why should those functions be private?  If all you are doing is examining data and writing it out, you should have an adequate public interface.

Comment: Nothing should be modifying the data but the whole point of encapsulation is to stop people accidentally doing things they shouldn't.

Comment: @Dan, but if you provide "friend" access to your exporters, can't they do something they shouldn't?  If you need to pass references around, pass **const** references around.

Answer (score 0):

Don't always resort to friend function because it can easily break the encapsulation of your class. Once friend, it can access all your private members no matter whether you hope it see or not.

In your case, you can simply provide some public interfaces to return the necessary data to clients which will produce different formats then. Furthermore, you can take a look at famous [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) if you're interested.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Friend only breaks the encapsulation from the perspective of *one* class- all the other clients remain encapsulated. When you use a public interface to return the data, though, then the encapsulation is broken for *everyone*.

Comment: @DeadMG, It's not the case. Well-defined interface only affects the encapsulation of current class without affecting the clients. It's up to the clients to decide whether to use that interface or not. It doesn't necessarily mean that client should change their interface as well.

Comment: @DeadMG, Another advantage of public interface is that you can well define the setters and getters separately which cannot be controlled by a friend anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think of for your (design) problem is a two fold solution:

- make for each class a function that serializes it to XML
- make generic functions that save from xml to any format you want:

  ```
  savefile_formatA(XMLNode* pRootNode, ofstream& fout);
  ```

this way you need to make only one serializing function for each of your classes and you can also serialize in any number of formats.

Comment: +1. Nice idea, bit overkill for my current project but I'll bear it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You would make it a method on DataClass and pass in the stream.