# Pattern name for 'formatting' objects

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have an `Order` value object with getters. Currently I pass this object to a `Formatter` class which creates a specific array structure using the getters. This array is then encoded as JSON and sent to a remote URL.

There are different URLs which require different array structures so I have created multiple `Formatter` classes which build the respective arrays. In a way these formatters 'wrap' the original object but i do not have a public getter method exposing the original object from a formatter. Also there is only one single public method exposed in each formatter called `format`.

Could these formatters be described as decorator/wrapper patterns or is this even a pattern at all? Im not explicitly *looking* to apply patterns for the sake of it, but i've discovered I was using other patterns in other parts of the code and renamed them appropriately to less confusion.

Comment: isn't this a serialiser? is the only purpose of `format` to serialise it to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Visitor](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Visitor/) pattern. Visitor allows for one or more operations to be applied to a set of objects at runtime, decoupling the operations from object structure.

Visitor is used in compilers. Once Abstract Syntax Tree(Object Structure) is created, then you can traverse AST for different purposes. 
In your case ObjectStructure can be Order class and different purposes mirrors different Formatters.

Comment: Here's a question where the answer shows a practical use of the Visitor pattern: [Design pattern for multiple output formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827998/design-pattern-for-multiple-output-formats)