# Which design pattern to serialise object Builder vs Visitor ?

Tags: design-patterns, builder, visitor-pattern, builder-pattern

I am trying to learn OOPS by examples. So I try to implement a object serialiser.The object is same but it can be serialised to either XML, JSON etc. I see two types of suggestions out there.

In this blog, they say we can use visitor/double dispatch to  serialise objects.

http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/10/31/be-not-afraid-of-the-visitor-the-big-bad-composite-or-their-little-friend-double-dispatch/

But, by definition we are building a serialised object from a complex object, so it make sense to create a XMLBuilder and JSONBuilder.

Now, which is the right way to do it ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827998/design-pattern-for-multiple-output-formats

Answer (score 2):

The point of learning design patterns is to prime your toolkit with solution ideas, not to follow dogma when solving problems for a test.

There's rarely a perfect choice in real-world scenarios. You have to balance trade-offs and decide what approach is best for the situation at hand.

Why not try both methods and evaluate what you like about the approaches?

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for the Visitor pattern provides an excellent overview of why you might want to choose the *Visitor* pattern. The "Use Case Example" in particular applies directly to your question.

> A fundamental operation on this type hierarchy is saving a drawing to the system's native file format.

Similarly, the [Builder pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) *can* be applied. But note that the focus with this pattern is the creation of a complex output from multiple sources. Builder formalizes the notion of a work in progress, allowing you to collect state until the output object can be produced.

I would argue that the Visitor pattern fits your needs more simply. But, the choice is up to you - that's the beauty (and curse) of software development!

Comment: I saw a different perspective to you in this case, so feel feel to correct me if wrong ;-)

Comment: I tend to agree with you - the point of my answer is to encourage critical thinking. The focus should be on designing a lean solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: @WillBickford...  wow thank you. that is lot to thing and work about, I will do my best. But thinking about your view that 'Builder formalizes the notion of a work in progress... collect state until the output object can be produced', isn't the serialiser slowly building/collecting the object information and finally producing the output ?

Comment: Builder is generally a solution to the problem of complex object initialization. "Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates." Noted by Scott Meyers in "Understanding what problem Visitor addresses" here: https://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_aha_moments.html.  The reason I suggested Visitor is that serialization can be implemented as a free function - there's no need to tie it directly to your object.

Answer (score 2):

Not withstanding the learned reply above of Bill Bickford and the Wiki example, there may be a need to take one step back.

You most definitely do NOT need **Builder** or **Visitor** to create serializers like XMLBuilder or JSONBuilder. The example at the CodeBetter link, is attempting to demonstrate **double dispatch** and its relationship to **Visitor Pattern**. In my opinion his example is confusing at best.

The C# XMLSerialiser object for example convents an object of whatever type it was constructed for to an XML document. No **Visitor** or indeed any other pattern in sight! There is a **separate process** to **persist** the serialised document (to whatever storage type) if needed, and when you combine these operations (serialisation and persistence) on an array of objects, this is where **Visitor** is applicable.

Instead of teaching every object in the array how to store itself in a range of possible formats, **Visitor Pattern** allows another object to "visit" and perform the storage operation. This is pretty much exactly the Wiki Visitor example, which is showing how different shape objects can be persisted, without each shape knowing how to save itself.

So you can study serialization in isolation from Visitor or Builder because they are NOT related... which I think you suspected!  If you are new to patterns, **Visitor is one of the most difficult to grasp**.....

Comment: Visitor is one of the most difficult to grasp.....
why??!!

Comment: @medunes. Obviously a very subjective assertion on my part. But visitor does involve 2 separate hierarchies of interacting objects so maybe in the absence of minimal examples, the intent is hard to see. When I started study of patterns from GoF, I was already familiar with  C++ double dispatch, and it was via this route that I could finally see clearly what visitor was doing!

Answer (score 2):

Object (acceptor) knows its structure, serializer (visitor) knows how to write down primitive/simple types. Both combined they can serialize/deserialize the whole object graph. That’s Binary Dispatch or Visitor.

It can be easier though, and faster at runtime, for the language or the programmer to expose the object metadata in a unified format, so anyone/anything could traverse the object graph without the double dispatch. Or even generate codecs with a compiler plugin when compiling the object.

Builder is usually used with the Named Arguments pattern to make constructing objects with multiple similar parameters less error-prone (with constructor one can easily swap two arguments of the same type). It is used by the generated Protobuf wrappers, but is not strictly related to deserialization otherwise.